# PdfBox transform PDF with several pages to one Image JPG

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf with several pages and I want to transform that to one Image.

My actual code create an image by pdf's page...

```
@Test
public void testImage() throws IOException {

    try {
        PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("download.pdf"));
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument);
        for (int x = 0; x < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); x++) {
            BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(x, 300, ImageType.RGB);
            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bImage, String.format(x +"__template_image.%s", "jpg"), 300);
            File imageFile = new File(x +"_template_image.jpg");
        }
        pdDocument.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How may I create only one image for all pdf pages ?

Comment: This isn't really a PDFBox question... you want to join several images into one. But it is quite possible that these images have different sizes. Anyway, the strategy is that you create one large image, then get a graphics device, then draw the individual images on the big one. But what should be done if they have different widths / heights? And should they be painted right of each other or below each other?

Comment: Yes I ve successed to do as you said :) thnks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution :

```
   @Test
    public void testImage() throws IOException {

        try {
            //Load PDF
            PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("download.pdf"));
            //Create the renderer
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument);
            BufferedImage joinBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(10, 10,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            for (int x = 0; x < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); x++) {

                BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(x, 150, ImageType.RGB);
                joinBufferedImage = joinBufferedImage(joinBufferedImage, bImage);
                //File imageFile = new File(x +"_template_image.jpg");
            }

            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(joinBufferedImage, String.format("template_image.%s", "png"), 150);
            pdDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


 public BufferedImage joinBufferedImage(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {

        //do some calculate first
        int offset = 5;
        int wid = Math.max(img1.getWidth(), img2.getWidth()) + offset;
        int height = img1.getHeight()+ img2.getHeight() + offset;
        //create a new buffer and draw two image into the new image
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(wid, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();
        Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
        //fill background
        g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, wid, height);
        //draw image
        g2.setColor(oldColor);
        g2.drawImage(img1, null, 0, 0);
        g2.drawImage(img2, null, 0 , img1.getHeight() + offset);
        g2.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }
```